# WCF method not allowed

Tags: wcf, asp.net-4.0

I'm completely new to WCF and I've created these functions.
On my localhost in works perfectly, but after putting it on IIS, I get errormessage 405 "Method not allowed" when I try to consume it.

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET")]
        [OperationContract]
        string EncryptZonderPaswoord(string tekst);

        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET")]
        [OperationContract]
        string EncryptMetPaswoord(string tekst, string paswoord);

        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET")]
        [OperationContract]
        string DecryptZonderPaswoord(string tekst);

        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET")]
        [OperationContract]
        string DecryptMetPaswoord(string tekst, string paswoord);
    }
```

...

Anyone an idea? Are there extra properties I need to set on my IIS?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my porblems.
This is what I had to do:

- install WCF in the .net framework serverside
- register framework 4.0 serverside
- in IIS: add my application to the .NET 4 pool instead of the default pool.